# NGINX+PHP-FPM: Is it possible associate php-fpm PID to access log entry?

Tags: linux, nginx, security, php-fpm

We have been using NGINX and php-fpm.

We've been noticing that some requests are hanging up for a long time (10+, 20+ minutes...) via **top** command.
Also, some suspect requests (I mean bots) were detected in access log entry (NGINX) but I’m not sure whether these suspicious requests have anything to do with those requests that are hanging or not.

**So my main question is:**

Is it possible (via config or whatever) associate php-fpm PID to URL entry in access log?
Or is there any tool that could help me with this task?

*Aditional info:*
We have the source code as we're the main developers.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It's problematic to identify the correct php-fpm process from the nginx side, because you are essentially communicate with a black-box over unix socket or tcp socket, not to mention threads.

You may attack the problem from the php side. You can use getmypid() from your php script, or if this is not your code, you might use the php_value auto_prepend_file option in the php fpm config. This way you can insert your own code at the start of every php file and log the pid along with the corresponding REQUEST_URI as you wish. You have the desired connection. Prepare to large iops on a busy site though...

If you just need the pid, it might be easier to enable php-status as documented here https://easyengine.io/tutorials/php/fpm-status-page/ and check yourserver/php-status?full

Comment: you are welcome ^-^ http://yourserver/php-status?full is what you need (my bad memory, edited).

Answer (score 1):

Generally this kind of issues is handled using a so called `RequestId`
Simply set two headers: `X-REQUEST-ID` and `X-CORRELATION-ID` and add them to logs both on nginx and on php side.

`RequestId` should be set to a random value (I use UUID) at the begining of each request and `CorrelationId` should be set to a random value at each user interaction. For small websites there is usually just one `RequestID` and one `CorrelationId`. If you use microservices, then each microservice would generate its own `RequestId`, but `CorrelationId` would be shared between them.

Implementation depends on your infrastructure, but a simple one could look like this:

```
# in nginx config
   location / {
      proxy_pass       http://upstream;
      proxy_set_header X-Request-Id $request_id; 
      ...
   }
# or
  location / {
    fastcgi_pass   unix:/path/to/socket;
    fastcgi_param  HTTP_X_REQUEST_ID $request_id;
    ...
  }

# This works because nginx generates a random string and stores it as $request_id
```

Then simply log your pid in PHP:

```
# in php-fpm config
# %p - pid
access.format = "[%p][%{HTTP_X_REQUEST_ID}e] %R - %u %t \"%m %r\" %s"
```

```
# or in php application itself
# index.php
<?php
file_put_contents('somewhere.log', sprintf('[%s][%d]', $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUEST_ID'] ?? 'N/A', getmypid()), FILE_APPEND);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have php-fpm status page enabled, you could consider checking the full mode to trace pids. For instance, using http://example.com/phpfpm-status?full should be possible to find out what is happening. (As a security related note: one should never leave such status pages publicly accessible.)

Answer (score 0):

You should utilize PHP-FPM's slow-log:
Setting `request_slowlog_timeout` as well as `slowlog` - see [php-fpm configuration docs](http://php.net/manual/de/install.fpm.configuration.php) - should provide you with a Stack Trace of all long running php-fpm processes; including their PID.